# Automatic doc comments in python using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, documentation, comments

This is a silly question.

I've used Visual Studio extensively in the past for developing applications in C#. With C#, I know I can enter '///' to automatically generate some doc comments. Right now, I'm using the python tools for Visual Studio. Is there a way to accomplish the same sort of comment automatically for python? I can't seem to find any settings for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would this be of help - https://wiki.python.org/moin/DocumentationTools?

Comment: I'm not as concerned with the documentation tool so much as automatic formatting of doc comments.

Comment: Something like this for visual studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599459/pre-fill-new-functions-in-eclipse-and-pydev-with-docstring-and-not-implemented

Answer (score 0):

I'm waiting for that feature as well. It currently doesn't exist with the [Don Jayamanne's Python extension](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode) (the main extension with millions of downloads), but you can follow the feature's progress [here](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/165).